# CSS doesn't work with AngularJS?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I started making my first AngularJS web app, following some YouTube tutorial. I came to the `ng-include` directive, and in the tutorial, the guy included the HTML code, then just made it look better by linking the index.html file (the file in which he included the code) to a CSS stylesheet (like people usually do it).

However for me, the CSS doesn't work on the included code, or on the index.html code itself. I made no typos, and the stylesheet is in the same folder as my html file. The code is ordinary:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheet.css">`

After seeing that, I figured maybe it has some trouble linking to the external sheet, so I deleted the above code, and used simple `<style></style>` in the head section, but that didn't work either. What could be the problem and how could I fix this?

Comment: maybe file path is not correct.

Comment: why you add in start of href "/" maybe this your problem?

Comment: as I said, it's in the same folder as the html file, as you can see above, there is no real path. and the name of the file is correct. i tried without that "/" but still didn't work

Comment: without Angularjs is work?

Comment: What does the html look like and the actual css.. what is the CSS code and what html classes or id's are used?  if you have it inside the actual HTML file with <style> tags, the issue could be in the actual HTML.

Comment: please post a specific example of html and css that doesn't work